# How can I create a Visual Studio 2008 menu option?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

I'm not sure if what I'm asking for qualifies as a full-fledged add-in, but here goes...

I'd like to put an option in one of the menus (Edit, perhaps) that gives me the opportunity to clean my text-- namely, sometimes in the course of business my quotation marks around strings wind up "slanted" instead of straight up and down, a consequence of cutting and pasting from outside sources.

It would be great to have a "clean quotes" option in VS that does a search and replace in the current document and puts in the correct quotes.  How might I go about doing this, and thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have different fonts in your code window? This doesn't happen to me. I can't make this happen to me. There is only one font for the code at a time.

Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Hi-- I don't have different fonts, but different ASCII characters.  For instance, one of the values used for a quote after cutting was ASCII 31 - “

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is under the Tools menu.  Click Tools->External Tools...  You can specify any program you want using macros for the current directory/file etc.  You will have to find/create the tool to do what you want, but it is pretty simple to add.  You can also go to the Tools->Customize... dialog to add a toolbar button or key binding.

For your particular problem you could very simply write a little command line to to fixup your file for you or use use something like [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).